# how to redrecit port 7777 request to 80 defaul tport

Tags: apache, url, redirect, port

1) If I have a Oracle application server web server and is accessible on 7777 port how can i redirect that request to port 80. This is in Apache.

Answer (score 0):

In complement to @Nik answer, if you cannot change the Web server configuration and you have an Apache which is independent of the Oracle Webserver, then make one VirtualHost in apache to be a **proxy** of the webserver running on 7777. Instructions you will need are:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  my_dns_alias_for_this_virtualhost.net
    ServerAlias  another_alias.net
    <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
        #
        # no open proxy
        ProxyRequests off
        <Proxy *>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all # or here specifiy allowed IPs
        </Proxy>
        ProxyTimeout 1200
        #exceptions first if any
        ProxyPass       /server-status  !
        #Proxy rewriting
        ProxyPass       /       http://theoracle_webserver:7777/
        ProxyPassReverse /      http://theoracle_webserver:7777/
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

This should be sufficienty if the Oracle webserver is not using too much hard-coded url in js and such. You will need mod_proxy to be enabled. You can maybe use 127.0.0.1:7777 as a replacement to 'theoracle_webserver:7777' If things goes bad, or you find hard coded ':7777' in the results you will have to check for mod_proxy_html rewriting.